# Route is changing but component is not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to create a GitHub explorer app. I can fetch data in my home component, but i want to give every username thier own seperate page that can filled with thier info. When i tried to write a github username, my app fetches the data but now routing a new route. It's only happening in my home component.

I'm using react / react router for my personal project "Github Explorer App" I wrote a SearchBar.js for when user write a Github name, it will bi fetched from github api and it should be displayed it their own route.
In the home, there should be only a searchbar, and after a user search a name there should be a route and displayed data for his own page. I tried something but now when i wrote a username route changes, but nothing happens! Thank you for replies, and here is my code.

I wrapped my App with BrowserRouter already. A normal route is working, but a username is not working.

My app folder

```
import HomeScreen from "./pages/Home/HomeScreen";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Results from "./components/Results/Results";

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />}>
        <Route path=":userName" element={<Results />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/hey" element={<Results />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

SearchBar.js

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import styles from "./SearchBar.module.css";
import Loading from "../Loading/Loading";
import { Link, useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Results from "../Results/Results";

function Hahh() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [cache, setCache] = useState({});
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const fetchData = (username) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setUserData(data);
        setIsLoading(false);
        setCache((prevCache) => ({ ...prevCache, [username]: data }));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  };

  const cachedData = useMemo(() => {
    if (cache[username]) {
      return cache[username];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }, [cache, username]);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    navigate(`/${username}`);
    if (username) {
      if (cache[username]) {
        setUserData(cache[username]);
      } else {
        fetchData(username);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          placeholder="Enter a GitHub username"
          className={styles.SearchInput}
          type="text"
          value={username}
          onChange={(event) => setUsername(event.target.value)}
        />
        <button className={styles.SearchButton} type="submit">
          Search
        </button>
      </form>
      {isLoading && <Loading />}
      {cachedData && (
        <div className={styles.ResultContainer}>
          <h2>User Data</h2>
          <p>Name: {cachedData.name}</p>
          <p>Public Repos: {cachedData.public_repos}</p>
        </div>
      )}
      {userData && !cachedData && (
        <div className={styles.ResultContainer}>
          {" "}
          <h2>User Data</h2>
          <p>Name: {userData.name}</p>
          <p>Public Repos: {userData.public_repos}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Hahh;
```

HomeScreen.js

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./HomeScreen.module.css";
import Logo from "../../assets/Hipo.svg";
import SearchBar from "../../components/SearchBar/SearchBar";

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.HomeScreen}>
        <div className={styles.ExplorerContainer}>
          <img className={styles.Logo} src={Logo} alt="/"></img>
          <div className={styles.ExplorerText}>GitHub Profile Explorer</div>
          <SearchBar />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

Results.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Outlet, useLocation, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function Results() {
  const { userName } = useParams();
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://api.github.com/users/${userName}`
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setUserData(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    fetchUserData();
  }, [userName]);

  if (!userData) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  console.log(userName);
  return (
    <div>
      <Outlet />
      <h1>{userData}</h1>
      <p>{userData.bio}</p>
      <img src={userData.avatar_url} alt="User Avatar" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Results;
```

This is base
[image: This is base]
This is when i wrote a name, route changing but the components does not
[image: This is when i wrote a name, route changing but the components does not]

Comment: What exactly isn't working? `Results` rendered by the nested `"/:username"` route not rendering? Is `HomeScreen` rendering an `Outlet` for the nested routes to render their content into?

Comment: When I type 'a username like =gabriel' there is a return coming up and route changing. But when I write a username a want to navigate user to a new route and render a skeleton css before data fetched,a after data fetched there should be only fetched data and info about user. No searchbar and the svg. Sorry if i couldn't tell correctly.

Comment: I see. Then can you [edit] the post to include the *relevant* code you are working with as part of a complete [mcve]? We can't address issues in code we can't see. What is the search bar and where is it rendered? From what I can tell you'll need to lift the searched-for state up to the parent component so the data can be passed down to the routes that care for it.

Comment: Replace `<Route path="/" ` with `<Route exact path="/" `

Comment: I added the missing parts. My problem is when i write a name, i don't want to see search bar or any homepage code. I want only to show them the info with new route. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the home screen with search bar UI to be rendered on its own route completely separate from the results page on its route, then `path="/:userName"` for `Results` can't be rendered as a nested route from `"/"` rendering `HomeScreen`.

Move/unnest the `<Route path=":userName" element={<Results />} />` route.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
      <Route path="/:userName" element={<Results />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Comment: I added some images about the situation. I want to show data in a route that has the same name with it.

Comment: @krina Does the solution I suggest ***not*** render the `Results` component on its own where it can consume the `userName` route path parameter? Did you try this code? If so, can you clarify what the issue is now that you are trying to resolve? Can you clarify your comment?

Comment: Omg! Thank you so much, it is fixed! When I changed the routes as you said, at first I don't know but it didn't work but now working perfectly fine. I had a problem before and you were the helper, thank you again :)

Comment: @krina Welcome again, glad to help. Cheers.